# Why IStream::Commit failed to write data into a file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I have a binary file, when I opend it, I used `::StgOpenStorage` with  `STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE | STGM_TRANSACTED` mode to get a root storage named `rootStorage`. And then, I used `rootStorage.OpenStream` with `STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE` mode to get a substream named `subStream`.

Next, I wrote some data with `subStream.Wirte(...)`, and called `subStream.Commit(STGC_DEFAULT)`, but it just couldn't write the data in the file.

And I tried `rootStorage.Commit(STGC_DEFAULT)` also, the data can be written. 
But when I used UltraCompare Professional - Binary Compare to compare the original file with the file I opend, a lot of extra data had been written at the end of the file. The extra data seems to be from the beginning of the file.

I just want to write a little data into the file while opening it. What should I do?

Comment: i know you've tagged this as winapi and windows but is there a reason you don't want to use the `std::ifstream` for this?

Comment: @CommanderBubble  My file is a compound document, so I choose IStorage and IStream.

Comment: @CommanderBubble They are using COM Structured Storage, which requires special handling. I do not believe COM is able to wrap an ifstream (that would require COM to be tied to the C++ runtime for this; there are technical reasons why this is undesirable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found out why there are extra data on my file.

**1**. Why should I use `IStorage.Commit()`

I used `STGM_READWRITE` mode to create a storage. It's called transacted mode. In transacted mode, changes are accumulated and are not reflected in the storage object until an explicit commit operation is done. So I need to call `rootStorage.Commit()`.

**2**. Why there are extra data after calling `IStorage.Commit(STGC_DEFAULT)`

According to this [website](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/ole/OLEIStorageCommit.htm):

The OLE-provided compound files use a two phase commit process unless `STGC_OVERWRITE` is specified in the `grfCommitFlags` parameter. This two-phase process ensures the robustness of data in case the commit operation fails. First, all new data is written to unused space in the underlying file. If necessary, new space is allocated to the file. Once this step has been successfully completed, a table in the file is updated using a single sector write to indicate that the new data is to be used in place of the old. The old data becomes free space to be used at the next commit. Thus, the old data is available and can be restored in case an error occurs when committing changes. If `STGC_OVERWRITE` is specified, a single phase commit operation is used.

Answer (score 0):

Binary file comparison will probably not work for structured storage files.  The issue is that structured storage files often have extra space allocated in them--to handle transacted mode and to grow the file.  If you want to do a file comparison, it will take more work.  You will have to open the root storage in each file, then open the stream, and do a binary comparison on the streams.

Comment: I just wrote about 5 bytes, but when I checked the file's attribute, it increased about 5KB, that's strange. And the extra data were not just be initialized with 0, but from the beginning to the position I overwrote of the file. And could you please tell me why subStream.Write() didn't work?